Can I use date part of an integer column as DISTKEY?
Currently I have a timestamp column store as BIGINT (as in the parquet file the datatype is long ), I would like to use the date part as DISTKEY, is that possible? I try to use ALTER TABLE table ALTER DISTKEY substring(time,0,10) but that is not allowed

No. The DISTKEY needs to be a specific column, not a calculated value.
Also, using part of a date does not sound appropriate for a DISTKEY.
In general, the DISTKEY should be a column that is commonly used in a JOIN, so that data related to each value is stored on the same node in the cluster.
See: Working with data distribution styles - Amazon Redshift
